# How to replace string to int in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, str-replace

I have this data in pandas and how can I convert "Address" to a number according to the price value?

```
    Area    Room    Parking    Address          Price
0   63       1      1          Shahran          1850000000
1   60       1      1          Chids            1850000000
2   79       2      1          Pardis           550000000
3   95       2      1          Shahrake         902500000
4   123      2      1          Shahrake         7000000000
```

Comment: And what number would it be? A rank based on the price?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IIUC, you can `rank` the prices by the mean Price per group of Address:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Address')['Price'].transform('mean').rank()
```

output:

```
   Area  Room  Parking   Address       Price  rank
0    63     1        1   Shahran  1850000000   2.5
1    60     1        1     Chids  1850000000   2.5
2    79     2        1    Pardis   550000000   1.0
3    95     2        1  Shahrake   902500000   4.5
4   123     2        1  Shahrake  7000000000   4.5
```

Or if you prefer dense values between groups:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Address')['Price'].transform('mean').rank(method='dense')
```

output:

```
   Area  Room  Parking   Address       Price  rank
0    63     1        1   Shahran  1850000000     2
1    60     1        1     Chids  1850000000     2
2    79     2        1    Pardis   550000000     1
3    95     2        1  Shahrake   902500000     3
4   123     2        1  Shahrake  7000000000     3
```

*NB. use the **`ascending=False`** parameter to rank the highest price first*